How to define dependency between jobs placed in different files in Github Actions?
When I merge a PR into main the event triggers a ReleaseBranchBuild and SemanticRelease flow (I don't know how the file with name, run-name, on and jobs properties). They are located in different files. The file structure is like below:
Example file:
name:
run-name:
on:
jobs:

The problem is that semantic release changes version numbers (and after this builds the common library package and pushes it into nupkg) in the csproj files. There are cases when the build starts restoring the project after the library version bumped but before the package is pushed by semantic release. At this the build fails.
To resolve this issue I need to define dependency between ReleaseBranchBuild.jobs.Test (test is the last step in the ReleaseBranchBuild flow) and SemanticRelease.bumpVersionNumbers step.
This is the main branch build
name: Backend Release branch build
run-name: backend_release_branch_build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'src/EG.Backend/**'

jobs:
            
  main_branch:
    name: Main Branch Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: Setting up Dotnet with ${{ vars.DOTNET_VERSION }} version
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ vars.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: EG Nuget repo
        run: |
          dotnet nuget add source --username Andras-Csanyi --password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/index.json"
          
      - name: Restore
        run: |
          dotnet restore src/EG.Backend/EG.Backend.sln
          
      - name: Build
        run: |
          dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore src/EG.Backend/EG.Backend.sln
          
      - name: Test
        run: |
          dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal src/EG.Backend/EG.Backend.sln

Semantic release
name: Release
run-name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  
  
  main_branch:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      - debug
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    permissions:
      contents: write
      issues: write
      pull-requests: write
      pages: write
      id-token: write
    
    steps:
          
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "lts/*"

      - name: Install Semantic Dependencies
        run: |
          npm install npm
          npm install semantic-release
          npm install @semantic-release/changelog
          npm install @semantic-release/exec
          npm install @semantic-release/git
          npm install @semantic-release/github
          npm install asciidoctor-plantuml

      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          cache: 'pip'

      - name: Debug Info Python tools
        run: |
          pip3 --version
          pip3 install --user bump2version

### this step should depend on backend_release_branch_build.Main_Branch job
### meaning this starts when that one finished

      - name: Semantic Release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN_FOR_SEMANTIC_RELEASE }}
        run: |
          npx semantic-release
          
      # nuget package publish has to happen after the version is bumped
          
      - name: Variables
        run: |
          APPVERSION=$(cat version.txt)
          echo "EGVERSION=$APPVERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo $GITHUB_ENV
          
      - name: Setting up Dotnet with ${{ vars.DOTNET_VERSION }} version
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ vars.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: Restore
        run: |
          dotnet restore src/EG.Common/EG.Common.sln

      - name: Build
        run: |
          dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore src/EG.Common/EG.Common.sln

      - name: Test
        run: |
          dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal src/EG.Common/EG.Common.sln

      - name: Pack
        run: |
          dotnet pack --no-restore --verbosity normal --include-symbols --include-source src/EG.Common/BusinessLogic.Contracts/BusinessLogic.Contracts.csproj

      - name: Publish
        run: |
          dotnet nuget add source --username Andras-Csanyi --password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/index.json"
          dotnet nuget push "/home/runner/work/EncyclopediaGalactica/EncyclopediaGalactica/src/EG.Common/BusinessLogic.Contracts/bin/Release/EncyclopediaGalactica.BusinessLogic.Contracts.${{ env.EGVERSION }}.nupkg" --source "github" --api-key ${{ secrets.TOKEN_PUBLISH_NUGET }} --skip-duplicate
          



You could convert the semantic release into a reusable workflow (trigger on workflow_call), and add the call to it as a job in the branch build workflow. That job can be defined as depending on the job that's already in there with needs.
